# How to install themes in Ubuntu?

Tags: themes

I want to install the *"Zoncolorxtra-Redmond"* theme on Ubuntu 13.10.

What is the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 5):

You can install the **zoncolor-themes** *(Zoncolorxtra-Redmond included)* from the [noobslab/themes](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/themes?field.series_filter=saucy) ppa.

**1)** Open a Terminal window and type the following to add the ppa.

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes`

**2)** Update the repos and install the zoncolor-themes & unity-tweak-tool *(to apply the theme)*.

- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool zoncolor-themes`

**3)**  Search for the unity-tweak-tool in the Unity Dash and open it.

[image]

**4)** Go to **Appearance > Theme** to choose your theme.

[image]

[image]

**Example Nautilus with Zoncolorxtra-redmond theme:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

zonColor Themes Pack is a complete set of elegant themes for Ubuntu and other GTK-based Linux desktops, aimed to bring professional looking and at the same time highly customizable (particularly in color customizations) themes, so that you can easily use/apply your very own color combination/color palette/color scheme for the themes.<sup>1</sup>

You can download the zonColor Themes Pack, which includes the zonColor Xtra-Redmond theme, from the [zonColor Themes Pack](http://www.fandigital.com/p/zoncolor.html) website.

To install, you can use installation launcher/script provided in the zonColor Themes Pack. Please see the included README files before using this pack. Instructions for installing dependency packages in Ubuntu 12.04+ are also found on the [zonColor Themes Pack](http://www.fandigital.com/p/zoncolor.html) website. Some of these dependency packages are already included in the default Ubuntu 13.10 installation.

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://www.fandigital.com/p/zoncolor.html</sub>